# How do I get the current user's username in Bash?

Tags: bash

How do I get the current user's username in Bash? Do I use [`whoami`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whoami)?

Comment: It seems none of the methods proposed so far work without relying on $USER or invoking a separate process. Is there no bash builtin to get the username without invoking a separate process?

Comment: When you've heard a command but aren't sure how to use it, checking `man whoami` is usually a good first stop to check for documentation.

Answer (score 754, accepted):

On the command line, enter

```
whoami
```

or

```
echo "$USER"
```

Comment: Just a quick note that $USER and whoami return different values if your running a command through ssh as another user. whoami returns the OS user and $USER returns the ssh user.

Comment: @BillMan, what does that even mean?  Could you provide an example?

Comment: In some cases, `$USER` is not set at all. Worse, it is just an environment variable, so it can be overridden by the user: `USER=thisisnotmyname bash -c 'echo $USER' # prints thisisnotmyname`

Comment: @sitaktif What do you suggest as a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SethMMorton I realise I made the issue sound worse than it usually is. To answer the question, though, using `whoami` (as you suggested) eliminates the problem altogether, assuming overridden environment variables is a potential issue in your context.

Comment: "current username" is slightly ambiguous. What do you want to get when running under sudo? "echo $USER" produces the name I logged in as whether run under sudo or not, while "whoami" returns "root" when run under sudo and my actual login name otherwise. Scripts that need to be run as sudo are more likely to be in that minority of scripts that have need of your login name rather than "root".

Comment: Won't work if 2 users (as defined in /etc/passwd) share the same uid.

Comment: @FCA69 I am always frustrated when someone says that something doesn’t work without offering a solution to the problem, because rather than being helpful it ends up just being a complaint. Why don’t you suggest a fix, or better yet edit the answer to make it more complete?

Comment: @SethMMorton: sorry about that. If you don't use "su" along the way in your session, "who am i" will provide the correct result, even if multiple users share the same uid. Best regards.

Answer (score 132):

An alternative to `whoami` is `id -u -n`.

`id -u` will return the user id (e.g. 0 for *root*).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this would be the way to go if portability is a concern as the `id` command and `-u` and `-n` flags are a part of [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html#tag_20_59)

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. `"${USER}"` and `whoami` both depend on how you log in. Specifically, login shells and sudo will set $USER, and `whoami` looks at the user attached to stdin. However, if you are running a batch job from cron, or you are running a startup script as a different user than root, then these will either output the wrong user (root) or nothing at all. This answer will return the correct value regardless by looking at process's user ID.

Comment: if you tried the command before adding untrue comments, you would see that the `-n` argument prints the username, just like the original question asked. see the following: `id -u -n` prints `brett` - even on darwin.

Comment: A great alternative when checking on live container instances with very few command line apps installed. `whoami` isn't installed on many of the lite images out there.

Answer (score 46):

Use the standard Unix/Linux/BSD/MacOS command [`logname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logname) to retrieve the logged in user. This ignores the environment as well as sudo, as these are unreliable reporters. It will always print the logged in user's name and then exit. This command has been around since about 1981.

```
My-Mac:~ devin$ logname
devin
My-Mac:~ devin$ sudo logname
Password:
devin
My-Mac:~ devin$ sudo su -
My-Mac:~ root# logname
devin
My-Mac:~ root# echo $USER
root
```

Comment: This was particularly helpful to me over whoami or $USER as I am using sudo to execute as another user, but want the original user not the sudo user.

Comment: BTW this is the best answer, not only for me personally but also to the purpose of the OP's question.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work in WSL https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/888

Answer (score 21):

A hack the I've used on [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) 9 and Linux and which works fine for both of them:

```
ps -o user= -p $$ | awk '{print $1}'
```

This snippet prints the name of the user with the current EUID.

**NOTE:** you need Bash as the interpreter here.

On Solaris you have problems with methods, described above:

- `id` does not accept the `-u` and `-n` parameters (so you will have to parse the output)
- [`whoami`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami) does not exist (by default)
- `who am I` prints owner of current terminal (ignores EUID)
- `$USER` variable is set correctly only after reading profile files (for example, `/etc/profile`)

Comment: Why do you need bash as the interpreter?  Nothing in the command line shown seems to be specific to any shell.  In fact, why even include the pipe through awk?  As far as I can tell, your `ps` command is everything required to display the owner of the current shell's pid.

Comment: For us as humans to disregard the superfluous information is natural. The awk portion isolates the desired data-- for variables or in general the computer that can't make on the fly assumptions just yet at this rudimentary level.

Comment: On Solaris, use `command -p id` (from a POSIX shell) or `/usr/xpg4/bin/id`. More generally, on Solaris, you'd want to modify your environment to put yourself in a POSIX environment (with something like `PATH=`getconf PATH` and be sure to run `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`) to avoid being stuck with commands from the 70s/80s.

Comment: 'ps: unknown option -- o'

Answer (score 12):

Two commands:

1. `id`  prints the user id along with the groups.
   Format: `uid=usernumber(username) ...`
2. `whoami` gives the current user name

Comment: $whoami isn't available as a *variable* in bash. You need to do either $(whoami), or \`whoami\` to actually execute the whoami command!

Comment: @RudolfMayer I fixed it

Answer (score 11):

When root (sudo) permissions are required, which is usually 90%+ when using scripts, the methods in previous answers always give you `root` as the answer.

To get the current "logged in" user is just as simple, but it requires accessing different variables: `$SUDO_UID` and `$SUDO_USER`.

They can be echoed:

```
echo $SUDO_UID
echo $SUDO_USER
```

Or assigned, for example:

```
myuid=$SUDO_UID
myuname=$SUDO_USER
```

Comment: It's worth noting that these variables are only set if you use `sudo` or `sudo -i`. If someone runs `sudo su -` (Which is still quite common for some reason), they will not be inherited, as the `su -` resets the environment.

Answer (score 7):

In [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) OS I used this command:

```
$ who am i     # Remember to use it with space.
```

On Linux- Someone already answered this in comments.

```
$ whoami       # Without space
```

Comment: Those 2 commands display 2 different informations. Just log as root, use "su - xxx", and see for yourself.

Answer (score 7):

```
REALUSER="${SUDO_USER:-${USER}}"
```

...gets you the **regular user** (if non-sudo) **→ or ←** the regular user **behind the current sudo call**.

Comment: The inner pair of curly brackets is not required -> `${SUDO_USER:-$USER}`. Or with whoami `${SUDO_USER:-$(whoami)}`.

Comment: How could i do it in nested quotes? e.g. `my_var="$('/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path' 'and/something/else')"`

Answer (score 5):

The current user's username can be gotten in pure Bash with the `${parameter@operator}` parameter expansion (introduced in Bash 4.4):

```
$ : \\u
$ printf '%s\n' "${_@P}"
```

The `:` built-in (synonym of `true`) is used instead of a temporary variable by setting the last argument, which is stored in `$_`. We then expand it (`\u`) as if it were a prompt string with the `P` operator.

This is better than using `$USER`, as `$USER` is just a regular environmental variable; it can be modified, unset, etc. Even if it isn't intentionally tampered with, a common case where it's still incorrect is when the user is switched without starting a login shell (`su`'s default).

Answer (score 4):

For [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (`ksh`), `sh`, etc. Many of your questions are quickly answered by either:

```
man [function]
```

to get the documentation for the system you are using or usually more conveniently:

google "man function"

This may give different results for some things where Linux and Unix have modest differences.

For this question, just enter "whoami" in your shell.

To script it:

```
myvar=$(whoami)
```

Answer (score 3):

On *most* Linux systems, simply typing [whoami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami) on the command line provides the user ID.

However, on Solaris, you may have to determine the user ID, by determining the UID of the user logged-in through the command below.

```
echo $UID
```

Once the UID is known, find the user by matching the UID against the `/etc/passwd` file.

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1,3
```

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1,3 | grep $UID | cut -d":" -f1

Answer (score 1):

This is a small simple example bash script I made for pushing my code to my personal gitlab, it spits out my current username in my commit message.

```
# !/bin/sh
# This example script is for pushing my code to gitlab 
echo Starting Push for user :  $(whoami), Please enter Commit Message 
below: 
read varMessage  
# this prompts the user for an input messsage , then saves the result in 
# a variable 
git add . 
git commit -m "$(whoami): $varMessage" 
git push -u "url_of_project" master
```

Resultant commit message in my personal gitlab looks like this:-

```
walexia : updated Matplotib example
```

Answer (score 0):

All,

From what I'm seeing here all answers are wrong, especially if you entered the sudo mode, with all returning 'root' instead of the logged in user.  The answer is in using 'who' and finding eh 'tty1' user and extracting that. Thw "w" command works the same and var=$SUDO_USER gets the real logged in user.

Cheers!

TBNK

Comment: How is this different from the answer **you** gave 4 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/39191736/3124333 ?

Answer (score -5):

Get the current task's user_struct

```c
#define get_current_user()              \
({                                      \
    struct user_struct *__u;            \
    const struct cred *__cred;          \
    __cred = current_cred();            \
    __u = get_uid(__cred->user);        \
    __u;                                \
})
```

Comment: The question was about how to get the username inside a bash script. This answer is about how to get the numeric user ID (not the username) from C code running inside the Linux kernel (such as from a custom Linux kernel module). It is not an answer to the question that was asked, it is an answer to a different question.