# $user or $whoami not working in a bash shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I am learning basic unix shell scripting now. I was trying a code from [here](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec01.html) to write my username but it is not working.

The code is:

```
#
# Script to print user information who is currently logged in , current date & time
#
clear
echo "Hello $USER"
echo "Today is \c ";date
echo "Number of user login : \c" ; who | wc -l
echo "Calendar"
cal
exit 0
```

I tried `$whoami` instead of `$user`, but still it is not showing my username. What can be the issue here? I am using vim editor in Ubuntu.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im bash shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If `$USER` is not working try, `$LOGNAME`.  If you have already learned about command substitution then you can use `$(whoami)` or `$(id -n -u)`. <sup>[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23931327/376535)</sup>
2. `\c` in `echo` wont work unless you specify with `-e` (stands for *enable interpretation of backslash escapes*).

   ```
   echo -e "Today is \c ";date
   ```

   It seems you want to prevent the trailing new line character introduced by `echo`. Another way to achieve this is to just add `-n`. Then you don't need `-e` and `\c`.

   ```
   echo -n "Today is "; date
   ```

Answer (score 3):

> I tried `` `$whoami` ``

What you probably mean to do is `` `whoami` `` or `$(whoami)`.

See [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Comment: In my case, **`whoami`** is working instead of **`$whoami`** within tildes.